# The most convenient set of infinitesimal generators of $GL^{+}(n,R)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

What is the most common/convenient set of infinitesimal generators of $GL^{+}(n,R)$ as a Lie group?

We can write any matrix element of $GL^{+}(n,R)$ in the form $\exp(t  A_{n\times n})$ where the basis for $A_{n\times n}$ are identified as the infinitesimal generators.

Naively, I think that one possible set could be those with only one entry being $1$ and all other entries are $0$. For example, for $GL^{+}(n,R)$ there are $9$ generators and some of them are

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 &0 \\0 & 0 &0\\0 & 0 &0\end{pmatrix}, \; \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 &0 \\0 & 0 &0\\0 & 0 &0\end{pmatrix}, \; \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 &1 \\0 & 0 &0\\0 & 0 &0\end{pmatrix},\; \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 &0 \\1 & 0 &0\\0 & 0 &0\end{pmatrix}, \cdots$

Comment: What is $A_{n\times n}$, do you mean the Lie algebra of $GL^+(n,\mathbb{R})$? If yes you probably want to read about the decomposition of a Lie algebra using the action of a Cartan sub-algebra. Fulton-Harris' introductory book to Representation theory is a nice reference to do this. Knapp's book "Lie groups, beyond an introduction" might also be a good reference for this.

Answer (score 1):

For the Lie algebras we have
$$
{\rm Lie}(GL_n^+(\mathbb{R}))\cong {\rm Lie}(GL_n(\mathbb{R}))\cong \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R}).
$$
This is just the vector space of $n\times n$-matrices with Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$. The matrices $E_{ij}$ with zero entries except for entry $1$ at position $(i,j)$ form a Lie algebra basis, the "infinitesimal generators".